# File > Open file is not working with me or I dont know how

Tags: android, eclipse

I delete eclipse and add it again in order to remove the blank screen, it worked but a previous project is in my C: in the workspace, I did "File > Open file" to that folder and I couldn't bring the folder in, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

*Dont worry*

**Two steps :**

**1st**

Change your default workspace.
Copy the complete project in another drive or folder.

**2nd**

just click on file tab on eclipse. click on import. select android-> existing code into workspace. browse your project .follow screen instructions(i.e mostly next)
and then you have your projectin eclipse

Comment: first try the second step if it doesn't work try from beginning

Comment: I collected the folder, in the import Project; the "Next" is not highlighted! After I clicked on "Finish" all the folders have been moved but in the eclipse they're empty!!!

Comment: Thats if I didnt choose "Copy projects into workespace" it will bring me an error says "Invalid project description"